# Always visible keyboard without other windows above or under it

Tags: unity, compiz, panel

I have a small touch-netbook with Ubuntu 11.10. I want to do either one of this (both solutions would be fine)

1. configure onboard (or any other touch-keyboard) to always be at the bottom and no other window can go above or under it. this includes maximizing!
2. create a panel/application window of my own with this behaviour

basically I want the same functionality as a panel and configure onboard/unity/compiz to obey this configuration or create my own panel.

Any hints would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to implement a hackish solution but it works surprisingly well!
I basicly create a panel-like window and inject the onboard gui into it.
Here is the draft:
https://gist.github.com/1329168